# Error Code 0xC0202091

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

Mi inconveniente es el siguiente; estoy integrando una conexión dinámica en SSIS dentro de visual conectado a una BD local, sin embargo cuando mi contenedor de bucles Foreach hace su recorrido me retorna el siguiente error:

> "[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on ImportFiles returned error code 0xC0202091.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure."

Leyendo sobre esto veo que es un error al omitir filas de datos en mi archivo de origen.
¿Hay alguna forma de solventar este inconveniente?

Comment: La respuesta, incluso tu respuesta va en la casilla de abajo que se titula Tu Respuesta. Si tienes cosas por añadir a la pregunta, edita la pregunta mejor y añade la info que creas relevante para que te respondan. La idea no es poner infinitos comentarios.

Answer (score 0):

El problema inicial lo solventé editando mi conexión de archivo, básicamente cambiando el número de filas de encabezados que se omitirán a: 1, ahora me encuentro trabajando en la conexión de origen y destino para que logre insertar las n filas.